# How to listen to events fired on page load

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

How do you write a CasperJS test that can listen to an event fired on page load? The event I'm interested in fires at the end of the page body.

```
// my-page.html
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        fireInterestingEvent();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried injecting a client script but it seems to load after `fireInterestingEvent()` has already fired.

```
// test/my-test.js
casper.options.clientScripts.push("test/lib/my-client-script.js")

// test/lib/my-client-script.js
listenToInterestingEvent();
```

I've also tried initializing a test object before the page finishes loading but my object isn't staying on the DOM.

```
// test/my-test.js
casper.on('load.started', function() {
  this.evaluate(function() {
    window.testObject = { foo: 'bar' };
  });
});

// my-page.html
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.testObject) listenToInterestingEvent(); // window.testObject is undefined
  fireInterestingEvent();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you it tried with the `url.changed` event?

Answer (score 1):

@Artjom B. figured it out in the comments section. Initializing an object on `window` during `url.changed` works but not during `load.started`.

```
// test/my-test.js
casper.on('url.changed', function() {
  this.evaluate(function() {
    window.testObject = { foo: 'bar' };
  });
});

// my-page.html
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.testObject) listenToInterestingEvent();
  fireInterestingEvent();
</script>
```